# How to customize wp-signup.php Wordpress MU

Tags: wordpress

Default Wordpress MU signup page not allowing to choice own password.

I want to customize like following page

http://blog.co.in/wp-signup.php

Answer (score 1):

The only solution to choice your own password in a Wordpress MU is to recode a part of ms-functions.php .

When you are registering to a Wordpress Mu it calls :
**wpmu_signup_user()** which calls **wpmu_signup_user_notification()** which send you the notification and the activation key.

After this you'll launch the activation link which will call **wpmu_activate_signup($key)**
And this is where the Password is generated :

```
$password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );
```

So you can try to put a form before launching this method, or you bypass all the activation stuff and directly call :

```
wpmu_create_user($user_login, $password, $user_email);
```

But i'm not sure it's the best solution.